# Xcode provisioning profile stopped working out of nowhere

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, provisioning-profile

7 days ago I built my unity apps on iOS using xcode provisioning profile (not dev account), all was working fine. Today I couldnt launch the apps on my iphone anymore so I though I need to rebuild and reinstall them on my phone again, but it was not working anymore. All the settings are the same as they were the last time, automatic signing, etc. Error:

> Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the
>   "Unity-iPhone" target's entitlements.

next error:

> Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile:
>   com.Vuforia.leanTouch" doesn't include the application-identifier and
>   keychain-access-groups entitlements.

which is weird because the project I do is `com.ARFoundation.Markerless` not `com.Vuforia.leanTouch`

Any ideas?

Comment: Also having this issue. Possible Apple outage? I get the exact same error, but with my bundle identifier and project name instead. I don't use these entitlements either, which is weird.